# Вывод нескольких class

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, появился вопрос, как мне реализовать показ сначала нескольких ID, а по клику на ссылочку всех имеющихся?
Например:

```
<div class="qwer"></div>
<div class="qwer"></div>
<div class="qwer"></div>
<div class="qwer"></div>
<div class="qwer"></div>
```

показать из них только 3 нижних с ссылкой "открыть все".

Comment: Проблема в выводе нужного количества на jquery, javascript, остальное, такое как возврат всех по клику на ссылку, думаю, справлюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
$('.qwer').slice(-3);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ve20s1Lm/

Comment: @knes, нет, не вышло, а можно попробовать как-то фильтрами вида: gt()? Вывод только трех, а к остальным .css("display","none").

Comment: >нет, не вышло  
Да что вы говорите?

http://jsfiddle.net/ve20s1Lm/

Answer (score 0):

Так вы же получаете массив объектов JQ, если так:

```
var tmp = $('.qwer')
```

Так вы потом и оперируйте с массивом tmp, оперируйте над последними 3-мя элементами (хоть в for обратный запехните), если я так все понял, должно сработать!